# postgresql select like one column two words

Tags: postgresql, select, sql-like

I want to make a query which select like two seperate words in a column. For example, My datas like this;

```
Paul Allen
Paul Smith Allen
John Allen
Paul George Allen
```

I want to select words which contains "Paul Allen". Like this;

```
Paul Allen
Paul Smith Allen
Paul George Allen
```

When I use "like", result is just Paul Allen.
When I use "similar to" '%(Paul|Allen)%' result is: all datas.
I don't want to these.
Thanks...

Comment: try `like '%Paul%Allen%`

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match several words, [use more](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) wildcard chars in same pattern. In your case:

```
like '%Paul%Allen%
```